# Get list of objects with related object

Tags: python

I've created two objects outside the database. One is `SERVICES` and one is `MODULES`.

I'd like to be able to get all `MODULES` related to a certain service. For instance, for the below example, I'd like to issue a command that basically says "Get list of Module Objects related to Service with key FACEBOOK" and have it return the two last Module objects.

```
class Module(object):

    def __init__(self, key, service, name):
        self.key = key
        self.service = service
        self.name = name

ALL_MODULES = [
    Module(
        'TWT',
        SERVICES['TWITTER'],
        'Twitter Tweets',
    ),
    Module(
        'FBC',
        SERVICES['FACEBOOK'],
        'Facebook Comments',
    ),
    Module(
        'FBP',
        SERVICES['FACEBOOK'],
        'Facebook Posts',
    ),
]

#dict of the above list
MODULES = dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES])
```

Comment: How about your SERVICES class? How to retrieve the service name you passed to it?

Comment: @FelixYan Hi Felix. What do you mean? I am wondering how to retrieve the module objects if I have the service key "FACEBOOK" which is listed in module.service.

Comment: Sorry I misread it. I don't think you can retrieve the key if SERVICES is a dict or something, I suggest you make a class like your `Module` to parse services so that you can retrieve the key later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `SERVICES` returns a `Service`-class having an `name`-attribute. If this is true, then you can get all modules related to a service (FACEBOOK for example) like this:

```
serviceModules = [m for m in ALL_MODULES if m.service.name == 'FACEBOOK']
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, except the = should be a == between name and 'FACEBOOK'